# USQL - How to extract the attribute value from xml file using xml extractor

Tags: xml, u-sql

How to extract the attribute value from XML file using custom extractor using U-SQL job. I can able to extract the sub element values from XML file.

```
sample Xml File:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Users>
<User ID="001">
    <FirstName>david</FirstName>
    <LastName>bacham</LastName>
</User>
<User ID="002">
  <FirstName>xyz</FirstName>
  <LastName>abc</LastName>
</User>
</Users>
```

I can able to extract Firstname and lastname using the below code.How can i get ID value as a part of csv file.

Sample U sql Job:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];
@input = EXTRACT 
  FirstName string,
  LastName string 
  FROM @"/USERS.xml"
  USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlExtractor("User",
    new SQL.MAP<string, string> { 
    {"FirstName","FirstName"},
    {"LastName","LastName"}
 );

 @output = SELECT * FROM @input;

 OUTPUT @output
 TO "/USERS.csv"
 USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Comment: I think it better if you can update XML and pass Id value as a property like FirstName or LastName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily in Databricks, eg

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE User
USING com.databricks.spark.xml
OPTIONS (path "/FileStore/tables/input42.xml", rowTag "User")
```

Then read the table:

```
%sql
SELECT *
FROM User;
```

If you must do it with U-SQL then using the `XmlDomExtractor` from the [Formats assembly](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats) worked for me:

```
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];

DECLARE @inputFile string = "/input/input40.xml";

@input =
    EXTRACT 
        id string,
        firstName string,
        lastName string
    FROM @inputFile
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlDomExtractor(rowPath : "/Users/User",
          columnPaths : new SQL.MAP<string, string>{
          { "@ID", "id" },
          { "FirstName", "firstName" },
          { "LastName", "lastName" }
          }
          );


@output =
    SELECT *
    FROM @input;


OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

My results:

[image: My results]